# MYSQL OR SQL SELECT with both COMPARE (HAVING) and GROUP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have three tables in a database and want to sum and compare in one SELECT statement.

The logic is that if one article runs low in stock it should be selected. An article runs low if the summarized `quantity` of all rows with the same `artID` in the table `Articles in stock` (an article can have several rows in the table and therefore needs to be summarized) is lower or equal to the column `warning` in the row with the corresponding `ID`. This is also `warehouse` specific, meaning that an article can be fully stocked in one warehouse, and at the same time running low in another. Which is why it is needed to summarize grouped on a specific warehouse.
Information about which warehouse is running low, and such as artNr for the article is also needed, which can be found in table `Articles`

```
Articles
+----+-------+---------+
| ID | artNr | warning |
+----+-------+---------+
|  1 | LA08  |       5 |
|  2 | LA09  |      10 |
|  3 | LA58  |       0 |
+----+-------+---------+

warehouse
+----+-------+
| ID | artID |
+----+-------+
|  3 |     1 |
|  4 |     1 |
|  5 |     2 |
+----+-------+

Articles in stock
+----+-------+-------------+----------+
| ID | artID | warehouseID | quantity |
+----+-------+-------------+----------+
|  1 |     1 |           3 |       10 |
|  2 |     1 |           5 |       15 |
|  3 |     2 |           5 |       45 |
|  4 |     1 |           3 |       20 |
|  5 |     3 |           5 |        4 |
+----+-------+-------------+----------+
```

Comment: What sense does the warehouse table make? Shouldn't there rather be a name column instead of the artID column?

Comment: It's for telling which articles exists in which warehouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a.id, s.warehouseID, sum(s.quantity)
from articles a 
join articles_in_stock s on a.id = s.artID
group by a.id, s.warehouseID
having sum(s.quantity) <= a.warning
```